# SQL Server re-uses the same IDENTITY Id twice

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I hope the question is not too generic.

I have a table `Person` that has a PK Identity column `Id`.

Via C#, I insert new entries for `Person` and the Id get set to 1,2,3 for the 3 persons added.

Also via C#, I perform all deletions of the persons with Id=1,2,3 so that there's no Person in the Table anymore.

Afterwards, I run some change scripts (I can't post them as they are too long) also on Table Person.

I don't do any RESEED.

Now the fun:

If I call `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Person')` it shows 3 instead of 4.

If I do an insert of Person again, I get a Person with the Id 3 added instead of Id 4.

Any idea why and how this can happen?

**EDIT**

I think I found the explanation of my question:

While performing DB Changes via SQL Server Management Studio, The Designer creates
a temp table Tmp_Person and moves the data from Person inside there. Afterwards he performs a rename of Tmp_Person to Person. Since this is a new table the Index starts again from the beginning.

Comment: Unless you can share the code to reproduce this there is nothing here to answer. The problem is almost certainly in "change scripts (I can't post them as they are too long) ".

Comment: @SeanLange yep. I think I found the issue. See my Edit.

Comment: Seems you answered it then.

Comment: Guessing you were using the GUI to add a column in the middle of a table, @gsharp , rather that using an `ALTER` statement to add it on the end? Using the GUI is useful, but it might not always do quite what you think.

Answer (score 2):

An `IDENTITY` property doesn't guarentee uniqueness. That's what a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE INDEX` is for. This is covered in the documentation in the remarks section, along with other intended behaviour. [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL) IDENTITY (Property) - Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017#remarks):

> The identity property on a column does not guarantee the following:
>
> - **Uniqueness of the value - Uniqueness must be enforced by using a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint or UNIQUE index.**
> - Consecutive values within a transaction - A transaction inserting multiple rows is not guaranteed to get consecutive values for the rows
>     because other concurrent inserts might occur on the table. If values
>     must be consecutive then the transaction should use an exclusive lock
>     on the table or use the SERIALIZABLE isolation level.
> - Consecutive values after server restart or other failures -SQL Server might cache identity values for performance reasons and some of
>     the assigned values can be lost during a database failure or server
>     restart. This can result in gaps in the identity value upon insert. If
>     gaps are not acceptable then the application should use its own
>     mechanism to generate key values. Using a sequence generator with the
>     NOCACHE option can limit the gaps to transactions that are never
>     committed.
> - Reuse of values - For a given identity property with specific seed/increment, the identity values are not reused by the engine. If a
>     particular insert statement fails or if the insert statement is rolled
>     back then the consumed identity values are lost and will not be
>     generated again. This can result in gaps when the subsequent identity
>     values are generated.
>
> These restrictions are part of the design in order to improve
>   performance, and because they are acceptable in many common
>   situations. If you cannot use identity values because of these
>   restrictions, create a separate table holding a current value and
>   manage access to the table and number assignment with your
>   application.

Emphasis mine for this question.

Comment: I wrote PK Identity Column :)

Comment: But it does guarantee `the identity values are not reused by the engine` and the question states they see `3` twice

Comment: Then see the latter point about "reuse of values" @gsharp . `IDENTITY` won't intentionally reuse a value, but that doesn't mean it won't either (if *someone* reseeds the table, for example). If you most stop an ID being reused then don't delete the rows from your table; use some kind of column to denote that the row is no longer "active" and write your query appropriately.

Comment: @MartinSmith an `IDENTITY` doesn't actually stop reuse of values; if a `RESEED` is issued you could even have 2 rows with the same ID in the same table. It won't "go back" and reuse a previous value on it's own, that is true enough, but it won't stop someone from "forcing" it to . This very likely means the OP, or someone, *has* reseeded the table.